# Find most recent records with specific criteria in Access

Tags: ms-access

I have a set of records that I would like to display the most recent records that match certain criteria.  I've done it wrong in the past where it would first pull the most recent records and THEN go and try and match criteria which would cause some of the records to disappear.  What I want to have the query do is to find the records that match criteria first and THEN have it pull the most recent records from that data set.  I need to have this query INSERT INTO a Table in Access.

I thought I had it sorted out, but I get an error "Your query does not include the specified expression 'SufGrpID' as part of an aggregate function

An example of the data:

When the query runs, I would like the results to be:

An example of the data:

SufGrpID 03 would be removed from the set because it is not the newest record for CaseID 123

SufGrpID 04 would be removed from the set because it is not of SufTypeID 14 and it is not of Status F

```
How the data looks
+----------+---------+-------------------------+-----------+--------+
| SufGrpID | CaseID  | CreateDate              | SufTypeID | Status |
+----------+---------+-------------------------+-----------+--------+
|  01      | 123     | 2010-08-20 07:42:32.000 |   14      |   F    |
|  02      | 234     | 2010-04-28 10:33:56.000 |   14      |   F    | 
|  03      | 123     | 2010-04-20 10:05:04.000 |   14      |   F    |
|  04      | 345     | 2010-08-20 11:18:42.000 |   12      |   I    |
|  05      | 345     | 2010-04-20 11:18:42.000 |   14      |   F    |
+----------+---------+-------------------------+-----------+--------+

Here's the code that did not work for me...

INSERT INTO [aStudent Base Data] ( [Self Suff ID], [Self Suff Create Date] )
SELECT dbo_sufscrgrp.SufGrpID, Max(dbo_sufscrgrp.CreateDate)
FROM dbo_sufscrgrp
WHERE (((dbo_sufscrgrp.SufTypeID)=14) AND ((dbo_sufscrgrp.Status)="F"))
GROUP BY dbo_sufscrgrp.CaseID;    

What I'd like the results to be. (EDITED at 1:33 CST)
+--------------+------------------------+
| Self Suff ID | Self Suff Create Date  | 
+--------------+------------------------+
|  01          | 2010-08-20 07:42:32.000 | 
|  02          | 2010-04-28 10:33:56.000 | 
|  05          | 2010-04-20 11:18:42.000 | 
+--------------+-------------------------+
```

Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: You should group by on any column that is not included in an aggregate function. Your GROUP BY hence should read `GROUP BY dbo_sufscrgrp.SufGrpID`

Comment: So the CaseID represents a student.  Whereas the SufGrpID represents the individual document.  I need to have it show me the most recent entry for each student (CaseID)  Every single row has a different SufGrpID, so that wouldn't help... I don't think.

Comment: I suggest you read up on how to apply GROUP BY within MS Access. If you want to take CaseID into account then you have to add CaseID to your SELECT statement. As said before, your GROUP BY should include *ALL* columns not used in aggregate functions. Your current statement violates that rule.

Comment: Ok.  I'll take another stab at it tomorrow with that in mind.  Thanks.

Comment: Review http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html#TopN

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MS Access SQL Get Latest Records From Each Category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23354848/ms-access-sql-get-latest-records-from-each-category)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the minimal dataset example, consider:

```
SELECT dbo_sufscrgrp.*
FROM dbo_sufscrgrp
WHERE SufGrpID 
IN (SELECT TOP 1 SufGrpID FROM dbo_sufscrgrp As Dupe 
    WHERE Dupe.CaseID=dbo_sufscrgrp.CaseID AND SufTypeID=14 and Status="F"
    ORDER BY Dupe.CreateDate DESC, Dupe.SufGrpID DESC);
```